# TFS Automated Build Dashboard

Tags: tfs, build, automation, dashboard

I've searched around and have not been able to find a TFS build dashboard.  Basic requirements are simply:
- view of ALL builds (in progress, last successful, history)
- test metrics (# of tests, coverage...)

Coming from a java background I'm used to solutions that give you all this (e.g. Hudson, TeamCity...) in one package.  We are trying to leverage what TFS offers now.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Most of this is available out of the box.

Comment: I don't think you can find a full feature tool fits all of your requirements. I had the same problem. Finally I had to write my own tool. Last week I decided to remove some specific features and publish it via codeplex. I think the first version of this add-in is more informative than some other tools which I found before for monitoring builds. I believe it is not the most suitable tool without your own change. Take a look at [tfsbuildinspector.codeplex.com](http://tfsbuildinspector.codeplex.com)

Comment: For TFS 2015/2017 , you can use [CatLight build monitor dashboard](https://catlight.io/a/tfs-build-monitor)

Answer (score 2):

i've been hunting for something along the lines of cruisecontrol's dashboard and eventually found something that fulfils about 60% of my requirement out the box. you should take a look at  team build screen. http://teambuildscreen.codeplex.com/

At my company we've modified its source to display builds across multiple team projects and to customize the ui in terms of the build detail displayed and the layout, obviously the source is available so if it doesnt suite your exact needs you can change it and keep your team happy until you find/build something a bit more to your liking.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I found something much better than the build notification tool, On Codeplex is something called the [Community TFS Build Manager](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/). It works, works quickly, and gives you a lot more information.

[Download](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=User&f%5B0%5D.Value=Community%20TFS%20Build%20Extensions)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try **TFS "Build Notifications" tool** :

- It isn't exactly a dashboard but you can see last builds of multiple projects.
- It provides a tray icon and show build results as they happen.
- It's built-in with TFS 2010 (and available in TFS 2008 with [Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15836)).
- When installed, you can find it here :
  Start Menu --> All programs -->Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 --> Team Foundation Server tools -->Build Notifications.

[image: TFS Build Notifications Tray Icon]
[image: TFS Build Notifications]

For more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc302402 : tutorial video.
https://blog.iannelson.uk/team-foundation-server-build-notification-tool/ : the screenshots comes from this page.

Comment: This is also the best option I have found, but it is severely lacking. One, it doesn't update itself to add new builds that are created. Secondly when you add one by hand you have to close and reopen the app to see the changes, and lastly it is slow and refreshes very poorly

Comment: I agree. It's incomplete, slow and consume to much RAM (RAM is cheap but it doesn't worth 50 MB of RAM for a resident notification tool). This tool should be open sourced ;-)

Comment: Ubikuity check out the new Community TFS Build Manager. I linked to it in my answer. It makes you wonder why Microsoft's is so slow....

Answer (score 0):

Which template are you using?  The CMMI Template for example ships with a report that holds all of that information.  You can navigate to Sharepoint Site -> Reports -> Builds -> Build Summary and get all of the information you described or by navigating there inside the Team Explorer view.  All of the templates offer similar reports.

While this will not be the dashboard view when you first hit the Sharepoint site, you are able to provide anyone a link to hit the page directly that wants to see the Build breakdown.

Aside from that, you can build a Web Part to display the information you are looking for.  While I haven't searched for a dashboard view that has that information (because it is easy to create a report to give me that information) I wouldn't be suprised if a third party vendor supplies it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was looking more from a "pull" perspective than a push (i.e. report).  At any point I'd like to look at a dashboard giving the build/coverage status of all the projects/solutions in our entire department (or a subset).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Finally I had to write my own tool. Last week I decided to remove some specific features and publish it via codeplex. I think the first version of this add-in is more informative than some other tools which I found before for monitoring builds. By the way, it may worth the effort.
Take a look at [tfsbuildinspector.codeplex.com](http://tfsbuildinspector.codeplex.com)

Comment: Let me remind you that it means **nothing at all** that it is open source and not commercial. If you want to advertise your Open Source project, Stack Overflow has a program for that - and it's even FREE. but you need to stop using answers to do it.